# NSKeyedUnarchiver is not invoking -initWithCoder: on device (but okay on simulator)

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I am encoding my object and saving it to a file as follows: 
`[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.parent toFile:@"gameScene.plist"];`

and decoding it as follow: 
`scene = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"gameScene.plist"] retain];`

In simulator the above decoding code invokes my class's `initWithCoder` method properly. But when I run the same in device, the 'initWithCoder`is not called nor the`init` method and a 'nil' object is returned.

Could anyone please explain whats wrong here?

**EDIT:** For testing purposes, I gave same set of statements in both `init` and `initWithCoder`, instead of decoding the subobjects in `initWithCoder` and commented out all the encoding in my `encodeWithCoder`.

Comment: That seems odd. Maybe make sure the `.plist` is properly created?

Comment: should I need to manually create the plist? Wont the `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: toFile:];` create the file?

Comment: It should create the file. But I mean, make sure that the file actually exists before you read from it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you can't write to the root directory on an iOS device? I think that a path of `@"gameScene.plist"` really means `/gameScene.plist`, which is not writable on an iOS device, but would be allowed on OS X. The `-archiveRootObject:toFile:` method is probably returning `NO` here, indicating that the file wasn't created successfully.

You may want to do something similar to this:

```
NSURL *documentsURL = (NSURL *) [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory: NSDocumentDirectory inDomains: NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [[documentsURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"gameScene.plist"];

BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: self.parent toFile: filePath];
NSLog(@"Archive Success... %s", (success) ? "YES" : "NO");

NSLog(@"File Exists... %s", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: filePath] ? "YES" : "NO");

id unarchivedObject = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: filePath] retain];
NSLog(@"Unarchive Success... %s", (unarchivedObject != nil) ? "YES" : "NO");
NSLog(@"Equal Objects... %s", [self.parent isEqual: unarchivedObject] ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer :) as u said, the file is getting saved to root in my mac... now everything works fine, thx again :-)

Comment: No problem. If you have any questions, my email is listed on my profile page, and I'll usually have an answer, even if it's just to redirect you. `c:`